# Setup headers for web app's IP security restriction with Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-front-door

How to define `headers` for IP security restrictions of an Azure Web App, with Bicep?

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/config-web?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#resource-format) says little about this, only that `headers` is an object.

```
ipSecurityRestrictions: [
        {
          priority: 1000
          name: 'AFD'
          tag: 'ServiceTag'
          action: 'Allow'
          ipAddress: 'AzureFrontDoor.Backend'    
          headers: {
            x_azure_fdid : [
              '3dc8865d-90c7-4b87-8edf-99726c56543a'
            ]
          }    
        }
]
```

Error is: `The 'x_azure_fdid' header is not supported!`

I tried with `x_azure_fdid`, `xazurefdid` or even `'x_azure_fdid'`, uppercase, etc... to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Front Door [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-faq#how-do-i-lock-down-the-access-to-my-backend-to-only-azure-front-door-), the header name is `X-Azure-FDID`

```bicep
headers: {
  'x-azure-fdid': [
    '3dc8865d-90c7-4b87-8edf-99726c56543a'
  ]
}
```

Comment: I thought It tried this one... Which is close to the ARM template syntax. Thanks Thomas.